# how to convert contents of a text file into individual array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

this is my text file

```
Id:1
Source:86876786
Destination:878979723
Date:1/16/2021 3:31:22 PM
Status: Failed
Network :Jio
```

I have to store everything into individual array.I have to display like this
id Source  Destination Date Status Network

Comment: Why an array? It looks like you need a class.

Comment: There isn't enough detail to answer your question fully, we can only really give pointers. What is an "individual array"? What does "display like this" really mean? Writing the values one after the other to the console?

Comment: Does your text file only ever have these 6 lines in, or will it have multiples of 6 lines? E.g. if there are 100 records, the text file will have 600 lines?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I was tasked with this I would perhaps have something to hold the data:

```
public class X {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long Source { get; set; }
    public long Destination { get; set; }
    public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Network { get; set; }
}
```

And then something to parse it:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

var exes = new List<X>();
var current = new X();

for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++){
{
    var bits = lines[i].Split(":", 2);

    if (bits[0] == "Id") current.Id = int.Parse(bits[1]);
    else if (bits[0] == "Source") current.Source = long.Parse(bits[1]);
    else if (bits[0] == "Destination") current.Destination = long.Parse(bits[1]);
    else if (bits[0] == "Date") current.TheDate = DateTime.ParseExact(bits[1], "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    else if (bits[0] == "Status") current.Status = bits[1].Trim();
    else if (bits[0] == "Network ") current.Network = bits[1];

    if(i % 6 == 5){
        exes.Add(current);
        current = new();
    }

}
```

It will tolerate lines in any order, but they have to come in groups of 6. If they will come in the same order, but might not be in groups of 6 (e.g. if the Status line is unknown then it's missing from the file) we can use a hash set to track if we've already read a value for the current item

```
var exes = new List<X>();
var current = new X();
var hs = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var bits = line.Split(":", 2);

    if (!hs.Add(bits[0]))
    {
        exes.Add(current);
        current = new();
        hs.Clear();
    }

    if (bits[0] == "Id") current.Id = int.Parse(bits[1]);
    else if (bits[0] == "Source") current.Source = long.Parse(bits[1]);
    else if (bits[0] == "Destination") current.Destination = long.Parse(bits[1]);
    else if (bits[0] == "Date") current.TheDate = DateTime.ParseExact(bits[1], "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    else if (bits[0] == "Status") current.Status = bits[1];
    else if (bits[0] == "Network") current.Network = bits[1];

}
```

If they change order and don't come in groups of 6, you need something else to delimit groups. Use JSON

--

Then just go through your `List<X>` and diplay them how you want. Give X a better name too